# how to show only textarea field, but not line under it?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I cannot solve an issue:

I have an html:

```
  <md-input-container class="itemDescription">
                <label class="itemFont">Description</label>
                <textarea placeholder="Add a description..."
                ></textarea>
            </md-input-container>
```

and CSS:

```
.itemDescription{
 width:100% !important;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

the result is next:
[image]

BUT I don't want to show white area under  text: "Add description..."
So if descripiton has 1 row = show just 1 row. if 2 rows = show just 2 rows, but without additional white area. How to do it?

Comment: Are you sure there is not some margin underneath the `<textarea>` element? If you can make a version in codepen or a jsfiddle I can try and help you. There is obviously some styling being applied to that element other than what is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Add below css, it will remove the line under the textarea

```
border-bottom : 0px
```

Comment: the same. I think it something to do with md-input-container margin or padding...but can find where is it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.I've put styles on textarea. and border on it. so it works now.
thanks!!!

Comment: I'd consider putting your answer and accepting it on here (if you can) so that if anyone else has the same problem in future they can use your answer! :)